# PropertyAccessor SchemaName (Outlook MailItem attachment)

Tags: c#, outlook, html-email, email-attachments

I'm trying to generate Outlook HTML-Mail with embedded image from my C# application. I've found out that I have to attach the image and referencing it in the HTML.

I've got these lines from [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/6c063b27-7e8a-4963-ad5f-ce7e5ffb2c64/how-to-embed-image-in-html-body-in-c-into-outlook-mail?forum=vsto):

```
string imageCid = "image001.jpg@123";

 attachment.PropertyAccessor.SetProperty(
 "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x3712001E"
, imageCid
);

 newMail.HTMLBody = String.Format(
 "<body><img src=\"cid:{0}\"></body>"
, imageCid
);
```

What I don't get is that schema "url" for the `SetProperty` Method. I don't have any clue how this comes together. [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.office.interop.outlook._propertyaccessor.setproperty%28v=office.15%29.aspx) tells that this is the way to specify the Property that I want to set, but how do I get to that `0x...` id?

Comment: Marco, I guess you just have to copy this line as it is. The mentioned line is a fixed address - not to be changed.

Comment: yes it works nicely this way... It's just, I don't like to copy code that I don't understand...

Comment: It's a kind of validator to the attached file/data, just this - I guess (I'm not sure) to provide a kind of online security check in any file sent as attachment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/utils.htm#xmapi for an overview of the MAPI property tags, both fixed and named. DASL property names are not really MAPI specific, they are just a way to encode in a single string value fixed (4 byte int) and named (GUID + string or integer id) MAPI property tags.

You can see DASL property names in [OutlookSpy](http://www.dimastr.com/outspy) (I am its author) - select a message, click IMessage button on the OutlookSpy ribbon, select the property that you are after, look at the DASL edit box.